# javascript not working in phonegap while navigating pages

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, multipage

I am making one application for android with jquery mobile and phonegap which contains 10 different html pages. All the pages works fine in browser . But java script is not working while navigating to some pages in following way .

- index >> page 1 >> page 5  .... not working
- index >> page 1 >> page    2 >> page 3 >> page 4 >> page 5 ... not working
- index >> page 5 ....    working

what should be the reason for javascript not working ? I am navigating pages using href attribute of anchor tag.

code for not working :

```
<a data-role="button" href="../friends/friends.html" data-icon="6_social_group" data-iconpos="top" data-theme="f" data-mini="false">Friends</a>
```

Code For working :

```
<a href="content/friends/friends.html">Friends</a>
```

Comment: which scripts are not working..?

Comment: Can you post the script you used for navigating

Comment: simple alerts are not working

Comment: any solution to this issue yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue but adding the following code made it work for me. Add the property

> rel="external"

`<a href="pagename.html" rel="external" data-role="button">Click Me</a>`

I hope it helps you too

Comment: ya it worked for me , Thanks . but i have combined my different pages into single page for reducing redundant code